# MotionEvent Y coordinates on and off UI thread differ by height of status bar

Tags: android

When I interrogate MotionEvent coordinates in a non-UI thread, I get Y(thread) = Y(UI thread) + status_bar_height. Does anyone know why this is?

```
override fun onTouch(view: View?, motionEvent: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
    Log.d(TAG, "Pre Event ${motionEvent?.x} ${motionEvent?.y}")

    Thread(Runnable {
        Log.d(TAG, "Post Event ${motionEvent?.x} ${motionEvent?.y}")
    }).start()
}

output:
Pre Event 395.45078 681.4934
Post Event 395.45078 729.4934
```

Answer (score 0):

MotionEvent objects are reused by the framework to prevent the expense and memory fragmentation caused by creating hundreds/thousands of them for every touch event over the life of the app (remember that if you move by so much as 1 pixel that's a potential move event).  If you need data off of the event, save it during onTouch in a local variable.  It may not be the same later on, either in an asynchronous function or another call on the UI thread.

Comment: Cheers. Why does this mean the event y coordinate for the same motion event is exactly 48px each time though?